# Find Dropdown Option Labels That Are Assigned in a Section

Tags: fieldtypes, drop-down

I can get a list of option labels available in a dropdown field using the code below.  Is there a way to get a list of option labels that have been assigned to entries in a specific section?

```
{% for cocktailTypes in craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('cocktails').getFieldType.options %}
    <p>{{ cocktailTypes.label }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to loop all entries of that sections to "collect" them.

```
{% set cocktailTypes = [] %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
    {% set cocktailTypes = cocktailTypes|merge([entry.cocktails]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for cocktailType in cocktailTypes|sort %}
    <p>{{ cocktailType }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```